# A young vegetarian adventurer

Tags: word, wordplay

A friend of mine wrote the following story. He always was one for using too many words though, and I think that has complicated this puzzle somewhat. Can you unravel it for me?

### A young vegetarian adventurer was once nearly married.

After watching his bride walk down the passageway between the chairs,

he had a change of heart, and left the land surrounded by the sea on which he lived.

There was no boat, but there was a rickety old set of wooden planks held together rope, over which he walked.

Once on the mainland, He walked for days, climbing until he reached the continuous elevated crest of the mountains.

He walked on, further and further, for what seemed like an indefinite period of time.

Eventually, he came across a sign: "The switch needs to be moved into such a position that the current can flow".

Looking around, the young adventurer saw that there was a projection out from the rocks on which he was standing, with nothing underneath it but air.

He walked to the point at which the projection out from the rocks stopped, and there flipped the switch.

### A voice spoke. "Say your name and you shall pass."

What did the adventurer say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His name is:

> **ABEL**

Note that each consecutive pair of lines in the story...

> contain descriptions of words that differ by just one letter at the start:
>
>  ...the passageway between the chairs = **AISLE**;
>  ...land surrounded by the sea... = **ISLE**.
>
>  ...wooden planks held together [with] rope... = **BRIDGE**;
>  ...continuous elevated crest of the mountains = **RIDGE**.
>
>  ...an indefinite period of time = **EON**;
>  ...a position that the current can flow = **ON**.
>
>  ...a projection out from the rocks... = **LEDGE**;
>  ...the point at which the projection out from the rocks stopped... = **EDGE**.
>
>  These letter differences spell out the name **ABEL**.

The mentions of 'vegetarian' add connotations of:

> the story of [Cain and Abel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_and_Abel), in which one brother brings a sacrifice of **vegetables** to God, while the other presents the best of his flock of sheep.
>
>  However, in the story the 'vegetarian' is Cain rather than Abel...